# How to Build Production Next.js with Custom Server (Nest.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nestjs

I need help on how should I do compile/build my project using Next.js when I use a custom server.

I actually use **Nest.js** (TypeScript Node.js Framework) as my Backend and wrap my Next.js inside it (since Nest.js is node based so I think this should work) and it actually working.

This is one of the tutorial that I followed: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/render-next-js-with-nestjs-did-i-just-made-next-js-better-aa294d8d2c67.

And when I tried to build production, Next.js give me error like this

[image: problem]

So basically, when I use `nest build` command, it successfully compiled but only the backend part (which is Nest.js).
Whenever I tried to run into `localhost`, it would error and said the same thing above.

And the same as the second command (which is I tried to add `next build` command), it would show the same error.

I know where is the problem is (they basically need the compiled `.next/` folder) but kinda confused how to solve this.
Do you have any idea on how I should tell the compiler that the `pages/` folder has been moved into `src/client/pages`?

[EDIT]
Just for your information, this is my folder architecture.

[image: Folder Structure]

---

Any kind of ideas would be a really help. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fixed my own issue right after several minutes I post this even I've struggle for like hours!

So, just want to let you guys know if anyone ever comes with the same issue. Somehow, my solution is comes because [this Next.js CLI docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli), so thanks to that.

What I did is just simply change the directory first into the right **Next.js** folder's code and start compile it. I did it from `package.json` build `scripts`.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production nest build && NODE_ENV=production cd src/client && next build"
    ...
}
```